# SettingWithCopyError when scaling subset of columns with StandardScaler

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe df with 100 columns:

```
index      | col1 | col2 | col3 | ...
2021-04-01 | qwe  | 1    | 1.1  | ...
2021-04-02 | asd  | 2    | 2.2  | ...
2021-04-03 | yxc  | 3    | 3.3  | ...
```

dtypes:

col1: category
col2: int32
col3: float64

I want to scale all columns that are not of type "category" AND return it as a dataframe, not a numpy array.

My code so far:

```
y_feature = "col2"
y = df[[y_feature]]  # Set predictor y
X = df.drop(
    [
        y_feature,
    ],
    axis=1,
)

days = (
    pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max())
    .to_frame(name="date")
    .reset_index()
    .drop("index", axis=1)
)
limit_training_days = int(len(days.index) * 0.85)
X_train_limit = days.iloc[limit_training_days, 0]
print(f"Date for training: {X_train_limit}")

X_train, y_train = (
    X.query("date <= @X_train_limit").squeeze(),
    y.query("date <= @X_train_limit").squeeze(),
)
X_test, y_test = (
    X.query("date > @X_train_limit").squeeze(),
    y.query("date > @X_train_limit").squeeze(),
)

categorical_feature = X_train.select_dtypes("category").columns.tolist()
num_cols = X.drop(categorical_feature, axis=1).columns.tolist()

X_train[num_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[num_cols])
X_test_sc[num_cols] = scaler.transform(X_test[num_cols])
```

After updating my packages it now throws this error for the last 2 lines of code:

> SettingWithCopyError:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

How can I scale only non-category columns (keeping category columns untouched) AND return it as a dataframe?

Comment: How is created `X_train` and `X` ?

Comment: @jezrael added the code.

Comment: I think need `y = df[[y_feature]].copy()`

Comment: This does not help, still getting the SettingWithCopyError.

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests: `X_train.loc[:, num_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[num_cols])` ?

Comment: Gives the same SettingWithCopyError :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you trying to change `X_train` and `X_test` which are parts of a bigger dataframe. Try:

```
X_train, X_test = X_train.copy(), X_test.copy()
```

before scaling.

You can also do:

```
X_train, y_train = (
    X.query("date <= @X_train_limit").squeeze().copy(),   # here
    y.query("date <= @X_train_limit").squeeze(),
)
```

Comment: That worked, error is gone. Thanks a lot!